# iOS Swift - Epson POS Printer - ePOS SDK - addTextSize - How to change text size back to original size?

Tags: ios, swift, epson, pos, epos

I'm building a POS on iPad using swift to print to Epson printers over ethernet connection.

I'm using Epson docs and sample projects to have the printers up and running no problem.

Now heres the problem:

I need to change text size (bigger) then revert back to original text size - I can initially change textSize no problem -> but when I revert back to the original size it does get smaller but it is not as small as the original. See below:

[image: Text-Size]

According to Epson docs - `addTextSize()` - is the method I am looking for and it accepts an Int value between 1-8 to scale both height and width (it states that 1 is the default value)

https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_epos_sdk_ios_en/index.php?vid=ref_epos_sdk_ios_en_epos2printerclass_addtextsize#BHIHFBFB

So here is my code:

```
func sendPrint(printer: Epos2Printer) -> Bool {
    var result = EPOS2_SUCCESS.rawValue
    let textData: NSMutableString = NSMutableString()

    result = printer.addFeedLine(2)
    if result != EPOS2_SUCCESS.rawValue {
        printer.clearCommandBuffer()
        MessageView.showErrorEpos(result, method:"addFeedLine")
        return false
    }

    textData.append("Food item       $12.00\n")
    textData.append("Food item       $12.00\n")
    textData.append("Food item       $12.00\n")
    textData.append("Food item       $12.00\n")

    // SEND AT ORIGINAL TEXT SIZE (Should be 1,1)
    result = printer.addText(textData as String)
    if result != EPOS2_SUCCESS.rawValue {
        printer.clearCommandBuffer()
        MessageView.showErrorEpos(result, method:"addText")
        return false
    }
    textData.setString("")

    // CHANGE TEXT SIZE BIGGER WIDTH (2,1)
    result = printer.addTextSize(2, height:1)
    if result != EPOS2_SUCCESS.rawValue {
        printer.clearCommandBuffer()
        MessageView.showErrorEpos(result, method:"addTextSize")
        return false
    }

    textData.append("ADDRESS               \n")
    textData.append("CITY                  \n")
    textData.append("STATE                 \n")
    textData.append("ZIPCODE               \n")

    result = printer.addText(textData as String)
    if result != EPOS2_SUCCESS.rawValue {
        printer.clearCommandBuffer()
        MessageView.showErrorEpos(result, method:"addText")
        return false
    }
    textData.setString("")

    // CHANGE TEXT SIZE BACK TO DEFAULT (1,1)
    result = printer.addTextSize(1, height: 1) 
    if result != EPOS2_SUCCESS.rawValue {
        printer.clearCommandBuffer()
        MessageView.showErrorEpos(result, method:"addTextSize")
        return false
    }

    textData.append("Food item       $12.00\n")
    textData.append("Food item       $12.00\n")
    textData.append("Food item       $12.00\n")
    textData.append("Food item       $12.00\n")

    result = printer.addText(textData as String)
    if result != EPOS2_SUCCESS.rawValue {
        printer.clearCommandBuffer()
        MessageView.showErrorEpos(result, method:"addText")
        return false
    }
    textData.setString("")

    result = printer.addFeedLine(2)
    if result != EPOS2_SUCCESS.rawValue {
        printer.clearCommandBuffer()
        MessageView.showErrorEpos(result, method:"addFeedLine")
        return false
    }

    result = printer.addCut(EPOS2_CUT_FEED.rawValue)
    if result != EPOS2_SUCCESS.rawValue {
        printer.clearCommandBuffer()
        MessageView.showErrorEpos(result, method:"addCut")
        return false
    }

    printer.beginTransaction()
    result = printer.sendData(Int(EPOS2_PARAM_DEFAULT))
    if result != EPOS2_SUCCESS.rawValue {
        printer.clearCommandBuffer()
        MessageView.showErrorEpos(result, method:"sendData")
        printer.disconnect()
        return false
    }
    printer.endTransaction()
    return true
}
```

Now I know a workable option is to set the textSize from the beginning - but I would prefer to keep the top and bottom the smallest size possible.

I have also tried specifying `EPOS2_PARAM_DEFAULT` as a parameter which produces the same results - I've tried 0 as the input which causes the textSize change to fail - I tried using a double like 1.5 or .5 but that doesn't compile

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

After tons of attempts i figured it out - I'll keep the post up since it might help someone in the future as iPads seem to be becoming more popular for POS solutions

So it appears the font also gets changed when you change the text size - I think it might be a bug in the Epos SDK because they state that the default font is `EPOS2_FONT_A` but it appears that the initial font starts as `EPOS2_FONT_B` -> then when you change text size it reverts font back to `EPOS2_FONT_A (default)`

If you want to keep it on the smaller font simply set `addTextFont(EPOS2_FONT_B)` in the beginning of preparing your print data

Comment: Have you attempted to add multiple print in queue? Or one need to wait for first print to complete to attempt for new print?